BTRFS errors after restoring system partition
After restoring my system partition with clonezilla, when I boot I get the partition forced read-only due to BTRFS errors. I'm quite sure the clonezilla partition image is OK
dmesg outputs these errors:
[   79.693242] systemd-journald[594]: File /var/log/journal/70cf9b43b18548dba2f9e8d59e694030/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[  102.571835] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p5): level verify failed on logical 21189033984 mirror 1 wanted 1 found 0
[  102.572056] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p5): level verify failed on logical 21189033984 mirror 2 wanted 1 found 0
[  102.572152] BTRFS warning (device nvme0n1p5): Skipping commit of aborted transaction.
[  102.572155] BTRFS error (device nvme0n1p5: state A): Transaction aborted (error -5)
[  102.572157] BTRFS: error (device nvme0n1p5: state A) in cleanup_transaction:2021: errno=-5 IO failure
[  102.572160] BTRFS info (device nvme0n1p5: state EA): forced readonly
[  143.474666] systemd-journald[594]: /var/log/journal/70cf9b43b18548dba2f9e8d59e694030/user-1000.journal: Journal file corrupted, rotating.
[  143.474681] systemd-journald[594]: Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/70cf9b43b18548dba2f9e8d59e694030/system.journal: Read-only file system
[  143.474687] systemd-journald[594]: Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/70cf9b43b18548dba2f9e8d59e694030/user-1000.journal: Read-only file system
[  143.475018] systemd-journald[594]: Failed to write entry to /var/log/journal/70cf9b43b18548dba2f9e8d59e694030/user-1000.journal (30 items, 889 bytes) despite vacuuming, ignoring: Bad message

Can these errors come from restoring the partition?
Looks like some hardware problem but I have Windows installed on another partition of the same disk and it works OK. Is an SSD disk.
I restored again the partition with same result, clonezilla gives no errors and reports that image is OK.
I tried to fix using gparted live, gparted tells that it can not fix the partition,
I also tried btrfs check --force /dev/nvme0n1p5, it fixes tons of errors and finish unexpectedly.
